# Downloading jquery library to project Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http:\api.jquery.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea. I want to download jquery library to have access offline to it in Intellij Idea in my Spring Project. So I typed "Alt + enter" on the link

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

and chose "Download library".
The library has dowloaded, and the problem is that after it I can't run my program, because all the time I see 
Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 4: http:\api.jquery.com
without any path. I have't even have something like written in my whole project.

When I had just global link to "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" and had internet access all worked properly.

I tried to download library in local file and put in header link to it actually after deleting library from intellij. But still don't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="number" id="myInput" name="myInput" onchange="countOfTryings(this)">

    <a name="toChallenge" href="http://some_web_site.com?parameter1=4">This is link</a>
    <a name="toChallenge" href="http://some_web_site_other.com?parameter1=4">This is link 2</a>

    <script>
        function countOfTryings(variable) {
            $('a[name="toChallenge"]').each(function () {
                var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
                var str = oldUrl.substring(0, oldUrl.indexOf("parameter1"));
                var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(oldUrl, str + "parameter1=" + variable.value); // Create new url
                $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want my program to change the urls of hyperlinks with name="toChallenge". To change the value of the request parameter "parameter1" to new value, what will be in input with id="myInput".

Comment: sorry, but library downloading (in IDEA) just downloads the file from the web to IDEA configuration directory. This file is not used in any way when you run your application, it's only used by the IDE for code completion. So your issue definitely has nothing to do with downloading

Comment: How do you run your app? Please attach a screenshot of the error message

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After submiting a report to Intellij Idea I got an answer, that JS libraries are added to the Java classpath which is a bug, and to fix thit problem I need to do next:
Project settings (ctrl+alt+shift+s by default) -> Modules -> in "Modules" select "Dependencies" -> find jquery dependency -> delete jquery dependency -> click "apply"

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem but deleting dependency did not help. I had to go to global libraries and delete jquery library as well.

Comment: Looks like in new version problem occurs already on global libraries. I had the same problem one day before too.

Answer (score 1):

1. [ctrl+alt+shift+s] -> Modules -> Dependencies -> delete jquery dependency
2. maven -> reload all maven projects

Answer (score 1):

As both [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11942935/jan) and [Odeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12342766/odeta) point out in their answers, this can be fixed by deleting the dependency in the module and global library.  However, I think I can refine this a little further.  When I looked under the global library, I found there was both the released artifact and a *link to the documentation*.  If you delete the documentation reference, it should fix the problem and the dependency can remain.